# How to prevent my jQuery slider to get "overClicks"

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery slider. When clicking repetativly on the arrows to move slides it continues to slide more slides, how do I create a pause in clicks when clicking reverentially?

```
//When clicking on the right: 
$('.scroll-right').click(function(){
    //margin-left the slide including -= :
 $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+singleSlide}, 
                                              slideAnimationSpeed, function(){
        currentSlide++;
        console.log('Current Slide: '+ currentSlide);
        if ((currentSlide+1) === totalSlides) {
            currentSlide = 5;
            $('#slide_'+nextSlide).addClass("sliderPoiner");
            $slideContainer.css('margin-left', '-83.3300012207031em');
        }
    });
    addTheShadowRight(currentSlide);
})

//When clicking on the left: 
$('.scroll-left').click(function(){
    addTheShadowleft(currentSlide);
    //margin-left the slide including -= :
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+singleSlide}, 
                                              slideAnimationSpeed, function(){
        currentSlide--;
        console.log('Current Slide: '+ currentSlide);
        if ((currentSlide) === 3) {
            currentSlide = 24;
            $slideContainer.css('margin-left', '-617.419875488281em');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code, but it sounds like you need to use `stop()` to prevent the animation queue building up.

Comment: I added my relevant code part

Answer (score 0):

```
//When clicking on the right: 
$('.scroll-right').click(function(){
    //margin-left the slide including -= :
 ->$slideContainer.stop().animate({'margin-left': '-='+singleSlide}, 
                                              slideAnimationSpeed, function(){
        currentSlide++;
        console.log('Current Slide: '+ currentSlide);
        if ((currentSlide+1) === totalSlides) {
            currentSlide = 5;
            $('#slide_'+nextSlide).addClass("sliderPoiner");
            $slideContainer.css('margin-left', '-83.3300012207031em');
        }
    });
    addTheShadowRight(currentSlide);
})

//When clicking on the left: 
$('.scroll-left').click(function(){
    addTheShadowleft(currentSlide);
    //margin-left the slide including -= :
->    $slideContainer.stop().animate({'margin-left': '+='+singleSlide}, 
                                              slideAnimationSpeed, function(){
        currentSlide--;
        console.log('Current Slide: '+ currentSlide);
        if ((currentSlide) === 3) {
            currentSlide = 24;
            $slideContainer.css('margin-left', '-617.419875488281em');
        }
    });
})
```

I've added the `stop()` code where u see the `->`

This prevents animations from queueing up. so at the very moment u fire something else the queue will be trashed and the animation stops.

You should always use this before any animation except u want that queue to actually build up.